# if we can have null value for the unique index, does the query has less time duration?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I want to add unique key of three columns `(a, b, c)`, Column  'a' is the primary key.
Is this possible?

```
----------
a  |  b   | c
1  | b1   | c1
2  | null | c2
3  | null | null
```

Is this possible as a unique key,  if we can have null value for the unique index, does the query have less time duration?

Comment: There's nothing prohibiting null values in a unique index, I doubt it has any impact on performance.

Comment: If `a` is a primary key, then any multi-column index that includes it is automatically unique, there's no need to specify this constraint explicitly.

Comment: There's not much point in creating a multi-column index that includes the primary key. Any query that matches column `a` will just use the primary key index, there's no benefit to using the multi-column index.

Answer (score 1):

All databases allow `NULL` values in a unique index.  However, they don't treat the `NULL` values consistently.

MySQL allows duplicates for `NULL` values, so you can insert as multiple `NULL`/`NULL` values (assuming the unique index is on `(b, c)`.

So databases would not allow duplicates.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4c1916d6956c3c87da18ea262584f028) is the same example on SQL Server, for instance.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9224bcb659f0d673087af024cb11ed9) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` is, by definition, `UNIQUE` and a key.

So, saying

```
PRIMARY KEY(a),
UNIQUE(a,b,c)
```

is a "dumb" thing to do.  So is `INDEX(a,b,c)`.  Having one index start with the same column(s) as another (`PRIMARY KEY(a)`) is almost never of any benefit.

If you want to lookup things by `b` and `c`, say `INDEX(b,c)` and/or `(c,b)`.

In InnoDB, the PK is implicitly tacked onto any secondary index.  That is `INDEX(b,c)` acts like `INDEX(b,c,a)`.

`UNIQUE(b,c)` would say that the combination of `b` and `c` uniquely identify each row.  *But*, in this context, `NULLs` are treated as distinct.

```
a  |  b   | c
--   ----   ----
1  | b1   | c1
2  | null | c2
3  | null | null
4  | null | c2
```

Now `UNIQUE(b,c)` is OK because NULLs are different.
But `UNIQUE(c)` would fail.

Performance is probably not an issue anywhere in this area.  Follow the advice above on building (and avoiding) indexes; then I can address performance further.